# Does javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket handle the ACKs automatically?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

My question might be silly and this is why there is no answer coming up when I am searching for it but here it goes.

Lets say I have the following block of code of my server-client application.

```
public void test(SSLSocket socket){
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream((socket.getOutputStream())));

    dos.writeInt(2);
    dos.flush();
}
```

What happens if for network reasons the sent integer doesn't get to the server? Does the socket handle the resending of the packet itself resending the data automatically or it has to be handled manually using threads and timeouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket` handle the ACKs automatically?

No, but TCP does.

Comment: right. I knew it was a silly one... It's all about layering :p

Comment: what happens though if an ACK never comes back? How is that case handled? I mean if an ACK doesn't come back then the msg is resent but that is for a limited amount of times. What happens after?

Comment: It times out and resets the connection.

Comment: can you please explain "resets"? what would happen in my example? just ignore the `writeInt()` since no ack is received and move to the next line?

Comment: After enough reads or writes such that the timeout has expired, you would get an `IOException: connection reset`.